# Using JobScheduler for time based notifications

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler

I need to show the user a notification at the same time every day (based on a user selecting the time it is shown). With API 25 and earlier I can use `AlarmManager` without a problem. However with API 26 (Oreo) it will crash my app if the app is in the background for more than a few minutes. Nothing I've done seems to prevent `AlarmManager` crashing after about a minute of the app being in the background.

Based on what I have seen online the only solution is to use a `JobScheduler`, but there doesn't seem to be anyway to have a JobScheduler start at a certain time and then recur every day. (I can have it run at a certain time by calling `setOverrideDeadline` or I can make it recurring by calling `setPeriodic`, but calling both throws and exception.)

This is my code for the JobScheduler (I have it set to recur every 15 seconds for testing, but I also want to be able to start it at a certain time):

```
private void setReminders(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED }, 613);
        return;
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_pref_file_name), ContextWrapper.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean showReminder = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.shared_pref_reminder_active_key), false);
    int hour = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.shared_pref_reminder_hour_key), 21);
    int minute = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.shared_pref_reminder_minute_key), 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long startUpTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 10000; //calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 10000;

    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder( 613, new ComponentName(getPackageName(), SefiraReminderJobService.class.getName()));
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE)
            .setOverrideDeadline(15000)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setPersisted(true);
    builder.setPeriodic(Math.max(15000, JobInfo.getMinPeriodMillis()));
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );
    if(jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build()) == JobScheduler.RESULT_FAILURE ) {
        Log.w("MainActivity.setReminders", "Something went wrong when scheduling the reminders" );
    }
}
```

This is my `JobIntentService` class:

```
public final class ReminderJobService extends JobIntentService {

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1234;
    private static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my-reminder-channel";
    private Notification notification;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Reminders", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("My Reminders");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                //.setTicker("ticker value")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))
                .setContentTitle("Reminder")
                .setContentText("Reminder Message").build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.ledARGB = 0xFFFFA500;
        notification.ledOnMS = 800;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest contains the following:

```
<service android:name="ReminderJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"></service>
```

As well as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

How can I send a recurring notification each day at a specific time on Android 26/8.0/Oreo even when the app is in the background?

Comment: I was able to use it by forcing the job to be called at a specific time using `setMinimumLatency` and `setOverrideDeadline` and then creating a new job at the end of the current execution. It seems a bit hacky though and I'm still wondering if theres a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This workable decision but with deprecated logic:

```
public scheduleEvent(int id, long scheduleTime) {
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = pendingIntent(id);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduleTime, pendingIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduleTime, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduleTime, pendingIntent);
    }

private PendingIntent pendingIntent(int id) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(app, EventReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("some event " + id);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 10, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Create **EventReceiver** don't forget add it in **AndroidManifest**

```
public class EventReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), EventService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, intent.setComponent(comp));
    }
}
```

Create **EventService**, also add it to the **AndroidManifest**

```
public class EventService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
        //Your logic here
    }
}
```